# show/hide button for leaflet legend

Tags: javascript, leaflet, legend

Is it possible to add a simple show/hide button on the leaflet map which will allow the user to see the legend on choice?

Here is my code for the legend:

```
    var legend0 = L.control({});
        legend0.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
    grades = ["Localisation", "Orientation"],
    labels = ["icon-gamze/location1-zoom1.png", "icon-gamze/location2-zoom1.png"];
     div.innerHTML += '<b>Localisation</b><br>' 
for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
       div.innerHTML +=
       (" <img src="+ labels[i] +" height='20' width='20'>") + grades[i] +'<br>';
}

       return div;
      };

       legend0.addTo(map);
```

Comment: You may achieve this quite easily using jquery .hide() and .show() methods, or using simple vanilla JS functions and CSS.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please exemplify? I'm quite new to the suite.

Answer (score 4):

For this, you need to write a few lines in Javascript. Many solutions exist, depending if you want to use JS and/or CSS frameworks or not. Here is below an example with jquery:

First, add a button somewhere in your page:

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggleLegend();">My button</button>
```

Then, in the function toggleLegend():

```
    showLegend = true;  // default value showing the legend

    var toggleLegend = function(){
        if(showLegend === true){
        /* use jquery to select your DOM elements that has the class 'legend' */
           $('.legend').hide(); 
           showLegend = false; 
        }else{
           $('.legend').show();
           showLegend = true; 
        }
    }
```

This target all the elements that have the class 'legend' of your page.

Have a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript#21070237 for a pure vanilla JS example of show/hide.

J.

Comment: Thank you @juminet for your answer, but I unfortunately I could not make it work out. Can it be due to the fact that I have a number of legends on my map?

Comment: Does it work at least for one legend? Did you include jquery in your page?

Comment: Yes, I included jquery. And, no I could not make it work for even one legend.  @juminet

Comment: there was an error in my code. Sorry, I hadn't try it before